# Airflow-Docker: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<project directory>'

Tags: python, docker, airflow

Trying to run airflow using docker in my windows laptop. But I'm having an error (as seen below). The error displaying in the log of my dag is saying that there is a:
-- PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../spotify_project'.

Note: also attached is the structure of my project file

What is the possible reason and work around for it? Thanks in advance

[image]

```
*** Reading local file: /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=spotify_dag/run_id=scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00/task_id=run_spotify_etl/attempt=19.log
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1160} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.run_spotify_etl scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1160} INFO - Dependencies all met for <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.run_spotify_etl scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00 [queued]>
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1357} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1358} INFO - Starting attempt 19 of 24
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1359} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1378} INFO - Executing <Task(PythonOperator): run_spotify_etl> on 2022-06-04 00:00:00+00:00
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 8522 to run task
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:79} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'spotify_dag', 'run_spotify_etl', 'scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '77', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/spotify_dags.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpfaha58h3', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpqi0j7yi6']
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:80} INFO - Job 77: Subtask run_spotify_etl
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {task_command.py:370} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: spotify_dag.run_spotify_etl scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host 93b139943859
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1572} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_EMAIL=***@example.com
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER=***
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID=spotify_dag
AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID=run_spotify_etl
AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE=2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00
AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER=19
AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID=scheduled__2022-06-04T00:00:00+00:00
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - ...Refreshing Token...
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Refresh token has been successfully retrieved.
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - ...Extracting spotify data from '2022-06-04 00:00:00'...
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - ...Connect to Spotify and establish GET Requests for 2022-06-04 00:00:00...
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - GET request from Spotify API is successful: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/player/recently-played
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1890} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../spotify_project/output_data/history_json_raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../spotify_project/output_data'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 171, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 189, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/run_spotify_etl.py", line 219, in call_spotify_etl
    a.call_refresh()
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/run_spotify_etl.py", line 214, in call_refresh
    self.retrieve_recentlyplayed()
  File "/opt/airflow/dags/run_spotify_etl.py", line 118, in retrieve_recentlyplayed
    Path("../spotify_project/output_data/history_json_raw").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1277, in mkdir
    self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1277, in mkdir
    self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/pathlib.py", line 1273, in mkdir
    self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '../spotify_project'
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1401} INFO - Marking task as UP_FOR_RETRY. dag_id=spotify_dag, task_id=run_spotify_etl, execution_date=20220604T000000, start_date=20220605T232112, end_date=20220605T232112
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:97} ERROR - Failed to execute job 77 for task run_spotify_etl ([Errno 13] Permission denied: '../spotify_project'; 8522)
[2022-06-05, 23:21:12 UTC] {local_task_job.py:156} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2022-06-05, 23:21:13 UTC] {local_task_job.py:273} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

Comment: Does ```../spotify_project``` exist?  Is ```SPOTIFY_PROJECT``` the actual path?

Comment: yup. it's the home folder of all the project files as you can see in the photo attached

Comment: The case of ```SPOTIFY_PROJECT``` isn't the same as ```spotify_project```, though I don't know if it's just the ide that's uppercasing the project path or if it is indeed capital letters, yet  your code expects a lower case.

Comment: it's just the ide i think. checking the file explorer. it's lower case in my end

Comment: I can't tell where this ```../spotify_project``` is referencing to, so would it be looking for a ```spotify_project```  under your SPOTIFY_PROJECT directory?  Is this being run within the ```airflow_docker``` path?

Comment: I edited the photo so you can see that the code where the error happened is in the run_spotify_etl.py. the `../spotify_project` it is referencing is the main folder. here is the line for that:           
`Path("../spotify_project/output_data/history_json_raw").mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open(f'../spotify_project/output_data/history_json_raw/raw_{self.yesterday.date()}.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, ensure_ascii=False, indent=4)`

Comment: Given that, and that you're running it in the ```dags``` directory, then wouldn't it be looking for the ```spotify_project``` in your ```airflow_docker``` path?

Comment: I'm not really sure how that path works. I just used the `../` to specify the relative path of the project file. When I try to run the dag in the terminal. It is running well.

Comment: What should I use to specify the path in the `spotify_project`? or is it even possible while using docker and airflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By working around the speculation of @ewong in the setup of the path. I checked it again and it is now working by using `.../spotify_project` with a three-dot.