# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '<project directory>'

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I am troubleshooting using airflow for some MLops work (see [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/unlocking-mlops-using-airflow-a-comprehensive-guide-to-ml-system-orchestration-880aa9be8cff)).
Here's the log error:

```
2c0cbc30645c
*** Found local files:
***   * /opt/airflow/logs/dag_id=ml_pipeline/run_id=manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00/task_id=run_feature_pipeline/attempt=1.log
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=non-requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: ml_pipeline.run_feature_pipeline manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1103} INFO - Dependencies all met for dep_context=requeueable deps ti=<TaskInstance: ml_pipeline.run_feature_pipeline manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00 [queued]>
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1308} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 1
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1327} INFO - Executing <Task(_PythonVirtualenvDecoratedOperator): run_feature_pipeline> on 2023-07-12 17:41:32.270307+00:00
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:57} INFO - Started process 73 to run task
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:84} INFO - Running: ['***', 'tasks', 'run', 'ml_pipeline', 'run_feature_pipeline', 'manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00', '--job-id', '9', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/ml_pipeline_dag.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpw2izgy7o']
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:85} INFO - Job 9: Subtask run_feature_pipeline
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {task_command.py:410} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: ml_pipeline.run_feature_pipeline manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00 [running]> on host 2c0cbc30645c
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1547} INFO - Exporting env vars: AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_OWNER='***' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_ID='ml_pipeline' AIRFLOW_CTX_TASK_ID='run_feature_pipeline' AIRFLOW_CTX_EXECUTION_DATE='2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00' AIRFLOW_CTX_TRY_NUMBER='1' AIRFLOW_CTX_DAG_RUN_ID='manual__2023-07-12T17:41:32.270307+00:00'
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {process_utils.py:181} INFO - Executing cmd: /usr/local/bin/python -m virtualenv /tmp/venv69qh8_nn --system-site-packages --python=python3.9
[2023-07-12, 17:41:34 UTC] {process_utils.py:185} INFO - Output:
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - created virtual environment CPython3.9.2.final.0-64 in 1833ms
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   creator CPython3Posix(dest=/tmp/venv69qh8_nn, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=True)
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/***/.local/share/virtualenv)
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     added seed packages: pip==23.1, setuptools==67.6.1, wheel==0.40.0
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:181} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/bin/pip install -r /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/requirements.txt
[2023-07-12, 17:41:37 UTC] {process_utils.py:185} INFO - Output:
[2023-07-12, 17:41:38 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - adding trusted host: '172.17.0.1' (from line 1 of /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/requirements.txt)
[2023-07-12, 17:41:38 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, http://172.17.0.1
[2023-07-12, 17:41:39 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Collecting feature_pipeline (from -r /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/requirements.txt (line 3))
[2023-07-12, 17:41:39 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   Downloading
...

[2023-07-12, 17:42:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Successfully installed Click-8.1.4 Ipython-8.14.0 PyMySQL-1.1.0 altair-4.2.2 asttokens-2.2.1 attrs-23.1.0 avro-1.11.0 backcall-0.2.0 boto3-1.28.2 botocore-1.31.2 certifi-2023.5.7 cffi-1.15.1 charset-normalizer-3.2.0 colorama-0.4.6 confluent-kafka-1.9.0 cryptography-41.0.2 dataclasses-0.6 decorator-5.1.1 entrypoints-0.4 executing-1.2.0 fastavro-1.7.3 fastjsonschema-2.17.1 feature_pipeline-0.1.0 fire-0.5.0 furl-2.1.3 future-0.18.3 great_expectations-0.14.13 greenlet-2.0.2 hopsworks-3.2.0 hsfs-3.2.0 hsml-3.2.0 idna-3.4 importlib-metadata-6.8.0 javaobj-py3-0.4.3 jedi-0.18.2 jinja2-3.0.3 jmespath-1.0.1 jsonpatch-1.33 jsonpointer-2.4 jsonschema-4.18.2 jsonschema-specifications-2023.6.1 jupyter-core-5.3.1 markupsafe-2.0.1 matplotlib-inline-0.1.6 mistune-3.0.1 mock-5.1.0 multidict-6.0.4 nbformat-5.9.1 numpy-1.25.1 orderedmultidict-1.0.1 packaging-23.1 pandas-1.5.3 parso-0.8.3 pexpect-4.8.0 pickleshare-0.7.5 platformdirs-3.8.1 prompt-toolkit-3.0.39 ptyprocess-0.7.0 pure-eval-0.2.2 pyarrow-12.0.1 pyasn1-0.5.0 pyasn1-modules-0.3.0 pycparser-2.21 pycryptodomex-3.18.0 pygments-2.15.1 pyhopshive-0.6.4.1.dev0 pyhumps-1.6.1 pyjks-20.0.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-dotenv-1.0.0 pytz-2023.3 referencing-0.29.1 requests-2.31.0 rpds-py-0.8.10 ruamel.yaml-0.17.17 ruamel.yaml.clib-0.2.7 s3transfer-0.6.1 scipy-1.11.1 six-1.16.0 sqlalchemy-2.0.18 stack-data-0.6.2 termcolor-2.3.0 thrift-0.16.0 toolz-0.12.0 tqdm-4.65.0 traitlets-5.9.0 twofish-0.3.0 typing-extensions-4.7.1 tzlocal-5.0.1 urllib3-1.26.16 wcwidth-0.2.6 yarl-1.9.2 zipp-3.16.0
[2023-07-12, 17:42:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - [notice] A new release of pip is available: 23.1 -> 23.1.2
[2023-07-12, 17:42:56 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - [notice] To update, run: /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:181} INFO - Executing cmd: /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/bin/python /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.py /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.in /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.out /tmp/venv69qh8_nn/string_args.txt
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:185} INFO - Output:
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1312, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hud/projects/energy-forecasting/output'
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1312, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hud/projects/energy-forecasting'
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1312, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hud/projects'
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - 
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - Traceback (most recent call last):
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.py", line 89, in <module>
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     res = run_feature_pipeline(*arg_dict["args"], **arg_dict["kwargs"])
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.py", line 59, in run_feature_pipeline
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     from feature_pipeline import utils, pipeline
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/lib/python3.9/site-packages/feature_pipeline/utils.py", line 5, in <module>
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     from feature_pipeline import settings
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/lib/python3.9/site-packages/feature_pipeline/settings.py", line 44, in <module>
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     OUTPUT_DIR.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1316, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1316, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1316, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/pathlib.py", line 1312, in mkdir
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO -     self._accessor.mkdir(self, mode)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {process_utils.py:189} INFO - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/hud'
[2023-07-12, 17:42:57 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1824} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/decorators/base.py", line 220, in execute
    return_value = super().execute(context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 374, in execute
    return super().execute(context=serializable_context)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 181, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 578, in execute_callable
    result = self._execute_python_callable_in_subprocess(python_path, tmp_path)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 434, in _execute_python_callable_in_subprocess
    os.fspath(string_args_path),
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 170, in execute_in_subprocess
    execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 193, in execute_in_subprocess_with_kwargs
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(exit_code, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/bin/python', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.py', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.in', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.out', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[2023-07-12, 17:42:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1350} INFO - Marking task as FAILED. dag_id=ml_pipeline, task_id=run_feature_pipeline, execution_date=20230712T174132, start_date=20230712T174134, end_date=20230712T174258
[2023-07-12, 17:42:58 UTC] {standard_task_runner.py:109} ERROR - Failed to execute job 9 for task run_feature_pipeline (Command '['/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/bin/python', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.py', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.in', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/script.out', '/tmp/venv69qh8_nn/string_args.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1.; 73)
[2023-07-12, 17:42:58 UTC] {local_task_job_runner.py:225} INFO - Task exited with return code 1
[2023-07-12, 17:42:58 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2653} INFO - 0 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check
```

To setup airflow, I did this:

```
# Move to the airflow directory.
cd airflow

# Make expected directories and environment variables
mkdir -p ./logs ./plugins
sudo chmod 777 ./logs ./plugins

# It will be used by Airflow to identify your user.
echo -e "AIRFLOW_UID=$(id -u)" > .env
# This shows where the project root directory is located.
echo "ML_PIPELINE_ROOT_DIR=/opt/airflow/dags" >> .env

# Initialize the Airflow database
docker compose up airflow-init

# Start up all services
# Note: You should set up the private PyPi server credentials before running this command.
docker compose --env-file .env up --build -d
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM apache/airflow:2.5.2

ARG CURRENT_USER=$USER

USER root
# Install Python dependencies to be able to process the wheels from the private PyPI server.
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y python3.9-distutils python3.9-dev build-essential
USER ${CURRENT_USER}
```

My project directory structure:

[image: blaa]

My issue is most similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72511791/airflow-docker-permissionerror-errno-13-permission-denied-project-directo), but it doesn't seem to be some error on relative imports as I am using absolute paths. I've also tried several different solutions based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62499661/airflow-dockeroperator-fails-with-permission-denied-error), but to no avail.

Has anyone encountered such problems before?

Comment: The very first error appears to be `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/hud/projects/energy-forecasting/output'`.  It's not clear to me whether this is on your real filesystem, or inside the docker container.  Does that directory exist, in either of those places?

Comment: BTW, don't use the `-e` argument to `echo` unless you have a very specific reason you need it, _and_ a reason why you can't follow the advice [given in the `echo` documentation](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) to use `printf` instead. (Also see [Why is `printf` better than `echo`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/3113) on [unix.se])

Comment: If you run your code through http://shellcheck.net/, btw, _at minimum_ it'll tell you to put `|| exit` after your `cd`s so you can't mistakenly run later code in a directory other than the intended one should that operation fail.

Comment: And in general, `chmod 777` is a serious smell; it grants write even to completely untrusted users like `nobody` (which is frequently used for things like sandboxing authentication of newly-created network connections).

Comment: In general, though, you've got code trying to create `/home/hud/projects/energy-forecasting/output` without having write access to that directory. It's a pretty straightforward error, no?

Comment: @John Gordon yes, that path for project directory is correct, but I am not sure where exactly this is called when running the airflow dag

Comment: @Charles Duffy thanks for those tips. Yes the path is correct

Comment: _that path for project directory is correct_ That's a bit of an ambiguous answer. 
You're saying that directory **exists**, both on your actual filesystem and also on the filesystem inside the container?

Comment: @John Gordon sorry I meant it exists in my actual filesystem. I am not sure if it exists in the container, I can't imagine it is - but how do I check if that's the case?

Comment: Okay, so the problem is likely that the target directory does not exist on the filesystem inside the container.  So you need commands in the Dockerfile to create the required directories.

Comment: The usual way to do that is to create a skeleton directory structure on your real filesystem, then use the COPY instruction in the Dockerfile to replicate that structure inside the container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies, the issue is rather trivial. I had a conflict export for `ML_PIPELINE_ROOT_DIR` in my bashrc, so airflow sometimes chose between the value in bashrc and in .env file.